# Proper way to store DB credentials in a .env file before pushing to GitHub

Tags: environment-variables, gitignore, dotenv

I am quite new to using github etc. basically my situation is I have my development and production DB's wired up through a `knexfile.js` (I am using `knex` and `PostgreSQL`). The credentials for my production DB is okay:

```
  production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL, //get from heroku
      ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10,
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations',
    },
  },
}
```

But my development DB has my credentials written into it - I obviously don't want these going up to GitHub.

```
  development: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'biblion',
      user: 'USERNAME',
      password: 'PASSWORD',
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10,
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations',
    },
  },
```

I tried putting my `knexfile.js` into `.gitignore` but that broke things so I had to do a hard reset to an earlier `git commit` and now I am a bit stuck about how to proceed. I believe I may have to use a `.env` file but I am uncertain about the process for doing this, properly adding the credentials to the `.env` calling those in the `knexfile.js` then safely pushing this up to GitHub.

I'd be grateful for some guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about changing those to `process.env` as you suggested ?

```
development: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'biblion',
      user: process.env.USERNAME,
      password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    },
    ...
  },
```

You could either start your script with those passed
`USERNAME=abc PASSWORD=123 node script.js`

Or use dotenv, through an .env file

You could then :

- Either use https://github.com/dkundel/node-env-run, to make sure it
  loads your node env variables locally before running the script
- Or require dotenv in the knexfile.js ( I am not sure if this would actually work or create issues with knex )

---

Other idea would be to have a different file to load for development, you keep the knexfile for your production and as it is for other env, but have a different filename that you don't commit to github for your dev env

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
let config;
if (env === 'production') {
    config = require('../knexfile.js')[env];
} else {
    config = require('../local-knexfile.js')[env];
}
```

This is not ideal since you'd end up with 2 files to maintain